# Python multiprocessing pool.map self._event.wait(timeout) is hanging. Why is pool.map wait not responding?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

multiprocessing pool.map works nicely on my old PC but does not work on the new PC.
It hangs in the call to

```
def wait(self,timeout=None)
    self._event.wait(timeout)
```

at which time the cpu utilization drops to zero% with no further response like it has gone to sleep.

I wrote a simple test.py as follows

```
import multiprocessing as mp
letters = ['A','B','C']
def doit(letter):
    for i in range(1000):
        print(str(letter) + ' ' + str(i))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool()
    pool.map(doit,letters)
```

This works on the old PC with i7-7700k(4cores,8logical), python365-64bit, Win10Pro, PyCharm2018.1 where the stdout displays letters and numbers in non-sequential order as expected.
Though this same code does not work on the new build i9-7960(16core-32logical), python37-64bit, Win10Pro, PyCharm2018.3

New PC bios version has not been updated from 2017/11 (4 months older)

pool.py appears to be the same on both machines (2006-2008 R Oudkerk)

The codeline where it hangs in the 'wait' function is ...

```
self._event.wait(timeout)
```

Any help please on where I might look next to find the cause.

Thanks in advance.

....
EDIT::
My further interpretation - 
1. GIL (Global interpreter Lock) is not relevant here as this relates to multi-threading only, not multiprocessing.
2. multiprocessing.manager is unnecessary here as the code is consuming static input and producing independent output. So pool.close and pool.join are not required either, as I am not post-process joining results
3. This link is a good introduction to multiprocessing though I don't see a solution in here.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows

Comment: please add the `tickers` to the example.

Comment: sorry the list passed in should have said pool.map(doit, letters).  I have corrected this now. Thanks for picking that up.

Comment: Uninstalled python 372 and installed 365.  This is working now.  Perhaps I have elected some options differently during the install, such as 'Make available to all users', or 'Precompile standard library'.  Perhaps this this could have had an effect on the operation of the multiprocessing pool map, or the threading.py functions that are imported?